# On Facebook, is there any way to restrict access to individual photos I'm tagged in?

Tags: facebook, photos

I would like to some people to be able to see some of the photos I'm tagged in, but not all of them.  Is this possible?

I know I can make a list of people that won't be able to see *any* of the photos I'm tagged in, but is there a way to do this on a per-photo basis?

Answer (score 2):

No. There's currently no way to do it from the side of the person who is tagged. You can ask the person who posted to increase security *for the album* but even that has been working quirky lately (Facebook shows some content to the friends of the tagged people).

Also, the only album where privacy settings are set per photo is Wall Photos. Everywhere else permissions are set for the entire album.

Comment: Mobile Uploads security is also set on a per-photo basis.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can manually review each tag as it happens and approve/decline the tag.

You can set this by going to [your privacy settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy). Select the `Edit Settings` link next to `Timeline and Tagging` and turning the `Review posts friends tag you in before they appear on your timeline` option on.

This will block everything you get tagged in (photos, posts, places checkins, etc) from showing up on your timeline (and subsequently your friend's newsfeeds / activity bar) until you approve the tag.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not give you any way to set who can see the photo.  Also, this setting only controls whether the post appears on your timeline; your friends can still see it in their News Feed even if you have not approved it for your timeline.

Comment: I do have this setting on.  But wait - @mark4o - are you saying that if I have not approved a tag, my friends will still see a post in their newsfeed that says "Jer was tagged in this photo"???

Comment: @mark4o whoa... that isn't what I've been seeing. However, it may also be due to the privacy setting of `Who can see posts that appear on your timeline because you've been tagged?` setting. I'll try to take a look at this tonight. I'll just have to find a Facebook friend willing to test this with me.

Answer (score 1):

That is only possible by setting the audience selector on the photo/album, but unfortunately photos you are tagged in will usually be owned by someone else and you may have no control over that.

If the photo is owned by a friend, they may be willing to change the audience to only their friends and not friends of people that are tagged (this is a new setting in the Custom dialog for newer photos), or they may be willing to post the photos to a closed or secret group (where only the group members can see the photos).

An alternative may be to post your own copy of the photo with whatever audience you like, and tag yourself in your copy and untag yourself in the original photo.